# How do I enable overlay scrollbars in Firefox?

Tags: 11.04, firefox, overlay-scrollbars

I like the overlay scrollbars that come with natty beta 2 by default! How do I enable them on fx4?

Comment: Duplicate of this bug report: [Bug #767040](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/firefox/+bug/767040)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

That is currently not possible, due to the libraries that Firefox's user interface is written using.

There is a bug report that you can mark as affecting you: https://bugs.launchpad.net/firefox/+bug/767040

Comment: @Ingo If they can enable them in all other default apps, why did they leave fx4?

Comment: I think applications like firefox, libreoffice have a different framework...for instance they had to manually program global menu for these applications make it work...I think it is something got to do with that.

Comment: Firefox's user interface is written using different libraries than most other Ubuntu programs. That means that indeed the devs have to adapt the scroll bars manually to it.

Comment: @Ingo @Nik where can I request to have such a feature?

Comment: Not necessary, it will be implemented for sure. They are probably already working on it :)

Comment: @Ingo great!waiting for it!

Comment: It didn't happen with 11.10. So now the question is: what about 12.04?

Comment: @IngoGerth I guess so :)

Comment: The developers are still not working on this. You can also [vote on the Mozilla Bugzilla bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/page.cgi?id=voting/user.html&bug_id=693146), [#693146](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=693146), to increase the importance of the bug.

Comment: The question is whether this will ever happen, now that Ubuntu switching to Unity 8.

Answer (score 2):

If the intent is to improve contrast for the existing Firefox scrollbar (not the overlay), a workaround is available in the form of an add-on which has been reviewed [here](http://www.ghacks.net/2012/01/03/change-the-color-of-the-firefox-scrollbar/) and [is available](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/noiascrollbars/?src=cb-dl-updated) via from the official Firefox add-ons page. To quote from there: "This add-on is mainly for people, who want different "high contrast" scrollbars for their default Firefox theme. These scrollbars can be more kindly for eyes".

I don't use that add-on since I already have the [Stylish](http://userstyles.org) add-on installed: this add-on allows one to modify scrollbars. My simplistic tweak is in the comments section of the first link.

Answer (score 2):

[This](http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/?content=146463) works well in 11.10. Try it in 11.04.

I've tried it in 12.04; it does change the size, but not the color.