# Gnome overlay scrollbar in Firefox

Tags: gnome, firefox, themes, gtk

I've been looking for a way to get Gnome's overlay scrollbar working in Firefox. By its appearance, it seems like Firefox is using the standard non-overlay GTK scrollbar, but I haven't found a way to get it to use the overlay version as illustrated below:

[image: Gnome overlay scrollbar]

I ran across [this article with a GTK 2 configuration](http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/?content=146463) but despite appearing to attempt to *mimic* the Gnome appearance, it doesn't seem to work as the scrollbars disappear altogether.

Is there any way to get the overlay scrollbar working in applications like Firefox?

Comment: I doubt you can currently do that for Firefox, Google Chrome, Chromium or LibreOffice.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I enable overlay scrollbars in Firefox?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/35242/how-do-i-enable-overlay-scrollbars-in-firefox)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[According to this related question](https://askubuntu.com/a/35775/25295), it appears that the overlay is only compatible with GTK applications, which unfortunately excludes Firefox, Chrome, LibreOffice and others.

In fact, [the `overlay-scrollbar` testcase page](http://testcases.qa.ubuntu.com/Applications/System/Scrollbars) specifically lists which applications *are* compatible.